# Python Tensorflow.keras LSTM: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (36, 36, 147) where an element of shape (36, 147) was expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've been struggling with the following code for some time now.

Basically, I'm getting either of the following two errors, depending on my adjustments:

`TypeError:` generator `yielded an element of shape (36, 36, 147) where an element of shape (36, 147) was expected.`

and

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 36, 147), found shape=(36, 147)`

I realize this has to do with my `data_generator()` function, as the error messages suggest that the outputs of my `data_generator()`: `train_data` and `val_data` are of different shape/dimensions than what is expected.

When I look at them:

```
print("Train Data element_spec:", train_data.element_spec)
print("Val Data element_spec:", val_data.element_spec)
Train Data element_spec: (TensorSpec(shape=(36, 36, 147), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(36,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
Val Data element_spec: (TensorSpec(shape=(36, 36, 147), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(36,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))
```

Which seems close. I understand that the first 36 represents the batch size, which is expected and what I want it to be. The second 36 represents time steps and 147 represents features per time step.

Note that `X` and `y` in the code below, and from which `train_data` and `val_data` are made, are both numpy.ndarrays with shape: `(418238, 36, 147)` and `(418238,)`, respectively.

Here's my MWE:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from kerastuner.tuners import BayesianOptimization
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
def data_generator(features, labels, batch_size):
    data_size = len(features)
    while True:  # Loop indefinitely
        for start in range(0, data_size, batch_size):
            end = min(start + batch_size, data_size)
            yield features[start:end], labels[start:end]  # Yielding a batch of features and labels

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: data_generator(features=X_train, labels=y_train, batch_size=36),
    output_types=(X.dtype, y.dtype),
    # output_shapes=([None, 36, 147], [None])  # Update this line
    # output_shapes=([None, 147], [None])  # Each sample has shape (36, 147). 
    # output_shapes=([36, 147], []) # TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (36, 36, 147) where an element of shape (36, 147) was expected.        
    # output_shapes=([147], []) # ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 36, 147), found shape=(36, 147)
    # output_shapes=([147], [None]) # ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 36, 147), found shape=(36, 147)
    output_shapes=([None, 147], []) # TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (36, 36, 147) where an element of shape (None, 147) was expected.
).repeat().batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
train_data

val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: data_generator(X_val, y_val, batch_size),
    output_types=(X.dtype, y.dtype),
    # output_shapes=([None, 36, 147], [None])  # Update this line
    # output_shapes=([None, 147], [None])  # Each sample has shape (36, 147). 
    # output_shapes=([36, 147], []) # TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (36, 36, 147) where an element of shape (36, 147) was expected.        
    # output_shapes=([147], []) # ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 36, 147), found shape=(36, 147)
    # output_shapes=([147], [None]) # ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 36, 147), found shape=(36, 147)
    output_shapes=([None, 147], []) # TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (36, 36, 147) where an element of shape (None, 147) was expected.

).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)  # Usually, you don't need to repeat validation data

# Define parameters
batch_size = 36
n_epochs = 10  # Define the number of epochs
steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) // batch_size 

def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM( units=hp.Int('units1', min_value=50, max_value=750, step=50),
                    batch_input_shape=(n_batch_size, X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), #36, 36, 147# ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, it needs to know its batch size. Specify the batch size of your input tensors:  - If using a Sequential model, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_input_shape` argument to your first layer.
                    return_sequences=True,                # default: False
                    seed=1,                               # Random seed for dropout.
                    stateful=True,                        # Boolean (default: False). If True, the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/66031/tensorflow-keras-what-is-stateful-true-in-lstm-layers
                  )
             )
    # print(model.summary())
    model.add(LSTM(units=hp.Int('units2',min_value=50,max_value=500,step=50),return_sequences=True)) # stateful=True here causes error
    model.add(LSTM(units=hp.Int('units3',min_value=50,max_value=500,step=50),return_sequences=True)) # stateful=True here causes error
    model.add(LSTM(units=hp.Int('units4',min_value=50,max_value=500,step=50)))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
                  loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model

# Bayesian Optimization Tuner setup
bayesian_opt_tuner = BayesianOptimization(
    build_model,
    seed=1,
    objective='val_loss',
    max_trials=25,
    executions_per_trial=1,
    directory='bayesian_optimization',
    project_name='keras_lstm',
    overwrite=True,
    max_consecutive_failed_trials=1
)

# Now use the train_data and val_data in the search method
best_hps = bayesian_opt_tuner.search(train_data, 
                                     epochs=n_epochs, 
                                     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                                     validation_data=val_data, # Using explicit validation data here
                                     verbose=1)

# Get the best set of hyperparameters
best_hps = bayesian_opt_tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?